# Does facebook images support Progressive JPEG?

Tags: ios, facebook, pinterest

In my iOS app, I'm using Pinterest's PINRemoteImage library to download images of Facebook pages, and I set the download property `setUpdateWithProgress` to `true`, so it will support it. But I see that every image shows up only when the download was completed.

Does anyone have a clue how to solve it? Do I need to add something to the URL?
This is the kind of URL that I use:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/<PAGE_ID>/picture?width=<WIDTH>&height=<HEIGHT>
```

Answer (score 0):

The property `updateWithProgress` has been deprecated. You should use the property `pin_updateWithProgress`.

Comment: Thanks, changed it, but still - it doesn't work. Do you know if Facebook infact support it for third party apps?